# Hiding unfilled rows in vertical v-data-table with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-data-tables

Following is executable code to demonstrate my problem.

Template:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      hide-default-header
      hide-default-footer
      class="elevation-1"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Script:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

This is the result:
[wide-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D0CL.png)

Looks all right with larger screens. But when I do have smaller screens, it starts to look like this:

[small-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlZNs.png)

**Question:** how do I hide the empty parts of the table at smaller screens(/when everything just becomes one column).

Comment: Not OK  if we put 0 if doesn't have value?

Comment: Hmm, that would be a solution, but sadly not a good solution for the project I am working on. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: well, it depends on your requirement, the solutions I provide are based on your current requirement as in the question.  Don't forget to vote for my answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can assign prop value in `v-data-table` `mobile-breakpoint="0"`,
> so now you can add your custom functionality on your desired screen
> size. On windows resize I'm calling the function `onResize` to
> calculate the width of the current window, and assign value to the
> `isMobile` variable to true if the window width is less than 769 (you
> can change this value), now we will add `<template v-slot:item="{ item }">` in the `v-data-table` to use our custom design as shown on demo.
> Different designs on the base of `isMobile` value.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
 data: () => ({
   isMobile: false,
       windowSize: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
      },
       headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
       desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
  
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.onResize();
  },

  methods: {
       onResize() {
      this.windowSize = { x: window.innerWidth, y: window.innerHeight };

        if (this.windowSize.x < 769) {
         this.isMobile = true; 
        } else{
           this.isMobile = false;
          }
      }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.24.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>


 <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
   <div v-resize="onResize" class="pt-20">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
      hide-default-header
      hide-default-footer
      mobile-breakpoint="0"          
    >
       <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
                <tr v-if="isMobile == false">
                  <td>{{ item.name }} not mobile view</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-right">{{ item.calories }}</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-right">{{item.fat }}</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-right">{{ item.carbs }}</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-right">{{ item.protein }}</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-right">{{ item.iron }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr v-else>
                  <td>
                    <v-list-item-group>
          <v-list-item v-if="item.name  != undefined">
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.name "></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
          
           <v-list-item v-if="item.calories  != undefined">
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.calories "></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
          
            <v-list-item v-if="item.fat  != undefined">
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.fat "></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
          
           <v-list-item v-if="item.carbs  != undefined">
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.carbs "></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
          
            <v-list-item v-if="item.protein  != undefined">
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.protein "></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
          
           <v-list-item v-if="item.iron  != undefined">
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.iron "></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
          
          
        </v-list-item-group>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </template>
    </v-data-table>
             </div>
    </v-app>
</div>
```